# Regular expression for matching page ignoring the directory before

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

From

```
http://www.example.com/my-page.html
```

To

```
http://www.example.com/my-dir/my-page.html
```

But the regex must not match

```
http://www.example.com/whatever-dir/my-page.html
```

I want to match only the html pages after `.com/`, not inside whatever folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^([^/]+)$ /my-dir/$1
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you @Shiva